# Check radio buttons in a loop with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've got three radio buttons within the same group.
The first one has a `checked="checked"`, other two are disabled: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6BZY/)

Is it possible (using Jquery or javascript) to:
 - check the next button in group automatically (with unchecking the previous one) with a 2sec delay, then check's next and so on until it reaches the last radio,
 - then loops back to the begining (the first radio) and starts checking again?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Update fiddle with the code i've got so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6BZY/1/)

Comment: yes it is possible....

Comment: first: you are using the same id three times, second: the other inputs are not disabled, third: you can do it with an interval function. what code do you have so far?

Comment: yep, i've fixed the id's. Also updated the fiddle with all i have so far. I'm not good with javascript, so i don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: id's should be different means we can do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML:

```
<input id="test-1" type="radio" name="testing" checked />
<input id="test-2" type="radio" name="testing" />
<input id="test-3" type="radio" name="testing" />
```

The JS (include jQuery):

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('input')
       .eq( ( $('input:checked').index() + 1 ) % 3 )
       .prop( 'checked', true );
},2000);
```

`( $('input:checked').index() + 1 ) % 3` will return `0`, `1`, or `2` and the corresponding radio button will be checked.

`setInterval()` runs the function inside each 2000 milliseconds.

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/rrikesh/P6BZY/8/)

**WITH STOP/START BUTTON**

The HTML:

```
<input id="test-1" type="radio" name="testing" checked />
<input id="test-2" type="radio" name="testing" />
<input id="test-3" type="radio" name="testing" />
<br /><br />
<a href="#" id="start">Start</a>
<a href="#" id="stop">Stop</a>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var intervalID; //global scope

function startCycle(){

    intervalID = setInterval(function(){
       $('input').eq( ( $('input:checked').index() + 1 ) % 3 ).prop('checked', true);
    },2000);

}

function stopCycle(){
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}

$('#start').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    startCycle(); 
});

$('#stop').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    stopCycle();
})
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/rrikesh/P6BZY/9/)

Here I assigned an interval ID to the loop each time the function `startCycle` is triggered and then used [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) to stop the loop with that particular interval ID.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution IMHO. Should be `.prop('checked', true)` though.

Comment: Yep, changed it to true. Is there a way to start/stop the loop?

Comment: @dd5 I added start/stop buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Javascript (short) version: [-FIDDLE-](http://jsfiddle.net/kardaw/fCYj5/1/)

```
function Check_next() {
    var wanted = document.getElementsByName("testing");
    for (var i = 0; i < wanted.length; ++i) {
        if (wanted[i].checked == true) {
            if (i == wanted.length - 1)
            {
                wanted[0].checked = true;
            } else {
                wanted[i + 1].checked = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

setInterval(function () {
    Check_next()
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have JQuery included in your project.
Second, use this script:

```
var index = 1;

var change = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (index > 3) 
            index = 0;
        $("#test-"+index).click();
        index++;
        change();
    },
    2000);
}

$(function () {
    change();
});
```

Comment: Thank you also for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function checknext(){
checkedbutton=$('input[name=testing]:checked');
if($(checkedbutton).is(':last-child'))
    $('div input').first().prop("checked", true );
else
  $(checkedbutton).next().prop("checked", true );
}

setInterval(function(){
  checknext();
},2000)
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6BZY/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Infinite loop:

```
<div id="input-wrapper"><input type="radio" name="testing" checked="checked" />
<input disabled="disabled" type="radio" name="testing" />
    <input disabled="disabled" type="radio" name="testing" /></div>

(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var inputs = $('#input-wrapper').find('input'),
            delay = 1000,
            index = 0,
            change = setInterval(function() {
                if (index >= inputs.length) index = 0;
                inputs.removeAttr('checked').not(inputs.eq(index)).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                inputs.eq(index).removeAttr('disabled').attr('checked', 'checked');
                index++;
            }, delay);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

please note that newer version of jquery use the prop method instead of attr

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6BZY/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how to set a delay, `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout( expression, timeout )
```

e.g.

```
setTimeout(alert("Hello"), 2000);
```

Here you can see how to check:

http://jsfiddle.net/P6BZY/

Combine this two and ‘Eureka!’!

Answer (score 0):

basically the timer triggers the checkRadio() function each second, and the function sets the radio button to active according to variable i

var i = 1;

```
function checkRadio(){
    $("#test-" + i).prop("checked", true)
    if(i == 3){
        i = 0;
    }else{
        i++;
    }
}

var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    checkRadio();  
},1000);
```

Comment: Description of what's going on for the OP?

Comment: first time posting didnt know, basically the timer triggers the checkRadio() function each second, and the function sets the radio button to active according to variable i

Comment: Might want to add that to your answer :) Welcome to StackOverflow!