# Check radio buttons in separate divs in a loop with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, radio-button

I'm have html tabs using radio buttons, as in this demo https://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/radio.php.
The markup is like this:

```
<div class="tab">
<input type="radio">
<p>Content shown when radio button is checked</p>
</div>

<div class="tab">
<input type="radio">
<p>Content shown when radio button is checked</p>
</div>

<div class="tab">
<input type="radio">
<p>Content shown when radio button is checked</p>
</div>
```

Now I'd like to run a loop to show one tab content after one automatically (and so checking the radio button automatically, with unchecking the previous one) with a delay, then loops back to the first radio and starts checking, showing the first content again.

I found a very similar solution here:[Check radio buttons in a loop with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309696/check-radio-buttons-in-a-loop-with-a-delay) but it didn't work for me, cause I've got the radio buttons in separate containers.

Is it possible with jQuery?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What have you tried? Show the "similar solution" and your attempts towards it. Don't expect us doing your work for you.

Comment: My mistake, i didn't add the link correctly. First question for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Few abstract suggestions (since a question is purely abstract):

- You can try to use a click event handler on their first common parent
     since it will bubble up there, and save currently checked radio to a
     variable, to be able to programmatically check/uncheck it.
- Or save    references to all radios to array and do with them
     anything you like    on every click on a radio.